# Metric Spaces and connectedness

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $X$ be a metric space. Let $A_0,A_1,A_2,\dots$ be a sequence of connected subspaces of $X$. Assume that $A_n \cap A_{n+1} \neq ∅$ for all $n \ge 0$. Prove that $\bigcup_n A_n$ is connected

Comment: By induction on $n.$ If $B$ and $C$ are open in $X$ with $B\cap C\cap (\cup_n A_n)=\phi$ and $B\cup C\supset \cup_nA_n,$  show that$ B\cap A_n\ne \phi \to B\supset A_n\to B\cap A_{n+1}\ne \phi.$ Works in any top'l space, not just metric spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Define $B_n = \bigcup_{i=0}^n A_i$, then then $B_n$ are increasing.

By induction show that all $B_n$ are connected, using the theorem that

(1) The union of a family of connected subsets that have a point in common is connected (e.g. theorem 23.3 Munkres, second edition).

Then apply (1) again to see that $\bigcup_n B_n = \bigcup_n A_n$ is connected (any point in $B_0 = A_0$ will serve as common point).